# Committing Crashlytics Framework on GIT

Tags: ios, git, ios7, xcode5.1, crashlytics

I have added Crashlytics to my iOS project, step by step, as instructed by Crashlytics. Then I went ahead and tried to commit the new modifications/Additions. However, when i check Crashlytics.h under Header folder under Crashlytics.framework from Xcode 5.1, it gives an error
- error: pathspec 'Crashlytics.framework/Headers/Crashlytics.h' did not match any file(s) known to git.
What is the solution? When i commit the remaining files without the checking Crashlytics.h it gets committed , but on next checkout it gives an error "Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h file not found" (in App Delegate).
Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in XCode. As a workaround, you can use another git client (for example: command line) to add the file and commit.